# Unable to set default gateway on a hosted Windows virtual server 

Tags: networking, virtualization, dhcp

I'm running Ubuntu server via Hyper-V and have successfully installed it but seem unable to ping the server or ping any other machines on the network from the server.

After doing a bit of [reading](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=25557) I've noticed that the default gateway isn't set but when I try and set it I keep getting error messages which I can't understand.

From [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-debian-ubutnu-set-default-gateway-ipaddress/) article I've tried

`ip route add default via 10.0.10.200`

Which reports: `RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted`

If I try running it prefixed with `sudo` but it reports:
`RNETLINK answers: No such process

I've editted `/etc/network/interfaces` but when I start the machine and type `netstat -nr` there is nothing listed.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong please?

**EDIT :**
/etc/network/interfaces contains:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

IP address: 10.0.10.82
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0

Comment: Try `sudo route add default gw 10.0.10.200`

Comment: @pl1nk - That returns "SIOCADDRT: No such process"

Comment: Could you post the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` ?

Comment: @pl1nk - Added.

Comment: Try: `sudo route del default` and then `sudo route add default gw 10.0.10.200`

Comment: `SIOCDEELRT: No such process`. All these error messages seem related to static routing when I google them, even though my network is set to use DHCP.

Comment: I can confirm that I run this command while I'm using DHCP.
Could you post the output of `route -n` ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3691/discussion-between-pl1nk-and-grandmasterflush)

Comment: That just returns the headers of the table (Destination, Gateway, etc...) with no information underneath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frustratingly, I had to rebuild the Ubuntu server to get this working. I had it connecting to the network before the problem as I was running updates and using apt-get. Having followed the same steps as I did yesterday and installing the same packages the machine is working without any problems.

The only thing I can think of is that either Hyper-V has corrupted the installation at some point or that there have been problems when the machine has gone into hibernation overnight. I've suffered problems with network connectivity after hibernation with Hyper-v & Ubuntu before but that was on an older version of the software and a re-start of the Ubuntu virtual server stopped the problem - this did not work today and the rebuild was the only solution.

I'd like to thank Pl1nk for sparing his time and taking me through all of the various network settings of the Ubuntu box as he tried to solve this problem.

Comment: Still working this morning, so it doesn't seem that it was the hibernate bug.